# margin is set to zero but it still showing

Tags: html, css

My html has 2 sections, margin is zero but it still showing

```css
.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: purple;
  border: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
</body>
```

[this is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfMxs.png)

Comment: can you fiddle the code

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: This is relevant: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 3):

It is not the margin. It is the  new lines  converted to "spaces" when displaying it.It is because of the `display:inline-block` of the div . You can either remove the space or remove that with comments  `<!-- -->` between the divs

```css
.box1 { width: 300px;
height: 450px;
background-color: green;
border: 0px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px; }

.box2 { width: 150px;
height: 300px;
background-color: purple;
border: 0px; 
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;}
```

```html
<div class="box2"></div><!--

   --><div class="box1"></div>
```

Comment: YES! 

Didnt know that, TNX.  :))

Comment: @MladenMilosavljevic You can read more about that here https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/